# nodejs принять файл

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как правильно принять файл?

Нашел такой код

Отправляю файл с таким содержимым

> какой-то текст

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_file">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

const http = require('http')
const fs = require("fs")
http.createServer( (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "POST"){
        req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("123.txt")).on("finish", () => res.end())
    } else {
        res.end()
    }
}).listen(3000)
```

После отправки сохраняется следующие:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryq8yTbH05DhHdOFP5 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_file"; filename="Новый текстовый документ.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> какой-то текст
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryq8yTbH05DhHdOFP5--

Откуда взялось

------WebKitFormBoundaryq8yTbH05DhHdOFP5... ?

Что я делаю не так?